# Configure browser request timeout for external resurces

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, request, connection-timeout

Is it possible to configure the browser's timeout for pending requests via `JavaScript`?

By browser requests I mean requests that the browser executes in order to fetch static resources like images referenced by url in html files, fonts, etc (I'm no talking about `xmlHttpRequests` made intentionally by the application for fetching dynamic content on a back-end server. I'm talking about requests that I'm unable to control, made automatically by the browser, like the aforementioned ones).

Sometimes the requests for such resources stay pending occupying a connection (and the number of connections is limited). I'd like to timeout (or cancel) those so they don't occupy connection.